# <Something>ように<可能形>程度には<something else>

Tags: grammar

I've studied Japanese for years and I've never come across this expression before. I saw this in a Twitch chat and the full quote was the following (I was the one who asked the thing in 「」 brackets):

> 「ゲーム以外には何か趣味がありますか？」軽く煽られてるように見える程度には汚れてしまった

If I'm not mistaken "/the quote/ 軽く煽られてるように見える" means "when someone says /the quote/, it looks like this person is trying to slightly agitate (you)". And when you end a sentence with 程度には汚れてしまった at the end, I think it means the speaker has experienced whatever is said before that (in this case, a phrase that apparently is being used to agitate people..?) so much that this person have come to only associate this thing with something negative (煽られてる).

But this is only a guess... Can someone break this down for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely correct.

In Japan(or at least Japanese Heavy Internet User), we even think "nice try" as something negative. It's just like that.

This is a bad culture in the old internet world(it still is though). On 2ch (now 5ch), a BBS we used to use a lot, there was a lot of behavior of putting others down in a roundabout way.
In my opinion, the real origin of this behavior comes from the (now rarely seen) disposition of Kyoto people. Reference (Japanese website): https://finders.me/articles.php?id=1955

The reason that streamer thought that your sentence is agitating him/she, is because he/she probably thought that sentence as "You're doing this (streaming) because you have no hobbies other than gaming, right?"

I would even think so if I was him/she, sadly.

Comment: How would you ask a neutral "Do you have other hobbies beside gaming?", with no judging, just being curious about any other hobbies they have?

Comment: I think there's no way to ask, unless you're talking to normal(non heavy internet user) people. We're just so complicated, to the point we don't have a neutral way to ask something very normal. I think maybe "煽るとかじゃなく、ゲーム以外の趣味って何かある？" could probably work but if I was being asked this I'd sense some irritating feel. In the first place, there is a vestige of a time when Japan culturally (as a bad trend) considered games to be a bad culture and didn't even allow people to profess their love for them, so it's a little tough to say that games are your main hobby. It's gotten better lately, though.

Comment: @Skye-AT Thanks for your answer! It sure can be challenging for a non-Japanese person to understand these things. Just to clarify, by "I'd sense some irritating feel", you mean you'd sense irritation from the person asking?

Comment: No, I feel irritated. Sorry if my English seemed weird.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for clarifying!